# disadvantages using Access or tools like Toad for mysql for creating queries

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is there any disadvantages using graphical query building tools, such as MS Access or Toadfor Mysql for creating queries for databases?

Comment: Are you talking about using a graphical query building tools? If so, I'd say it's only a problem if you don't double-check the results of the query builder. Any particular reason you're asking? P.S. Your question is something of a matter of opinion rather than strictly a programming question, so it's likely to get closed. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - your question is both opinion based ("unprofessional" is context specific), and rather vague - Access and Toad are very different tools!

Comment: Sorry, yes i mean using a graphical query building tool. No im asking because im not strong in SQL and i like using this tools.

Comment: Ah - that's better. Please clarify the question accordingly - "graphical query building tools, such as MS Access or Toad"

Comment: Be wary of guis which do things for you in the assumption that your underlying server is is at a level compatible with the gui which can lead to gui generated code being ahead (or behind) the server and either failing to syntax or conversely failing to take advantage of new features (yes phpmyadmin I'm looking at you).

Comment: You;ll generally find they're fine for building fairly simple queries but will often not be usable, or will produce inefficient results once you need something more complex. You should always check the SQL they produce. In the meantime, work on improving your SQL skills and after a while you'll find it's actually quicker and easier not to use the graphical tools!

Answer (score 1):

Graphical query tools can make complicated databases seem simpler, and can make working with a joins a little easier.

However...

If you don't really understand what you're trying to achieve, or how the schema works, they will often give you incorrect results without you noticing. For instance, a common problem is the "cartesian join", where you haven't limited the conditions for the join sufficiently. In "raw" SQL, you'll notice very quickly that you get far more results than you expect; in a nice GUI, with limited screen space for query results, that might not be so obvious.

If the schema isn't "clean", with explicit primary and foreign keys, the visual tools often have to guess at how the schema is supposed to work, and which tables join to which others. This may make it easy to create queries that *look* sensible, but are really just nonsense.

Personally, I found that once I got more than a couple of joins into a query, it was just easier to work in raw SQL than using the visual tools. I'd also suggest that if SQL is a significant part of your job, you'll benefit from learning the language directly.